# A test running with nosetests fails with ImportError, but works with python command

Tags: python-3.x, pythonpath, nosetests

When run a test with `python mycore/tests4extractor.py` it works. If run the test with  `nosetests ./mycore/tests4extractor.py` it fails with `ImportError: No module named extractor`. I am in the `helpers` folder.

The project structure is:

```
helpers/
    mycore/
        __init__.py
        extractor.py
        tests4extractor.py
```

Setting PYTHONPATH to the absolute path to `helpers` and/or `helpers/mycore` doesn't help.

**Answer**

tests4extractor.py:

```
    import mycore
    from extractor import extract
```

should be changed to:

```
    import mycore
    from mycore.extractor import extract
```

And python should be run with `python -mmycore.tests4_strings`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `tests4extractor.py` contain `import extractor`?

Because `mycore` is a package, you need to use absolute imports:

```
from mycore import extractor
```

or relative imports:

```
from . import extractor
```

Comment: You are right! I will update the question to include code snippet.

Comment: Hmm, after the update python fails with similar `ImportError:  No module named mycore`. But nosetests works.

Comment: To make python work I had to run it with `python -mmycore.tests4_strings`